# Prevent removing data after publishing update

Tags: ios, database

I've a music app which sync musics and save them into local storage.
Here is my question, after publishing new version of my app, when the user updates the app, will these musics remove? If yes, how can I prevent this action?

Should I save them into database like realm? are databases keep unchanged after updating to a new version?

thanks.

Comment: You can test this yourself during development. Build and run your app. Add data as needed. Now change some code, then build and run the updated app. See, your data is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting new versions only updates the code , so anything inside the local storage remains as it is , unless you manually remove it , also using any database approach like coredata / realm will make no difference